# How to loop through menu items in including all level menu items (Asp Vbnet )

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

**Here is my Code**

```
Protected Sub NavMenu_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NavMenu.PreRender
    Dim a As String = Replace(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, "/Home.aspx", "/")
    For Each i As MenuItem In NavMenu.Items
        If i.Target = a And Not i.Target = "" Then
            i.Selected = True
        End If
        If i.Target = "" Then
            i.Selected = False
        End If
        For Each aa As MenuItem In i.ChildItems
            If aa.Target = a And Not aa.Target = "" Then
                aa.Selected = True
            End If
            If aa.Target = "" Then
                aa.Selected = False
            End If
            For Each b As MenuItem In aa.ChildItems
                If b.Target = a And Not b.Target = "" Then
                    b.Selected = True
                End If
                If b.Target = "" Then
                    b.Selected = False
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

The problem is for each child level in menu i need to  repeat code.

*I need to know that is there any way to loop all menu levels, regardless how many levels, at once, with only one for each function.*

**Someway Like**

```
For Each i As MenuItem In NavMenu.Items and childitems
            If i.Target = a And Not i.Target = "" Then
                i.Selected = True
            End If
            If i.Target = "" Then
                i.Selected = False
            End If
Next
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Sounds like you could use recursion to solve this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: i think so. But i couldn't got the idea to make a recursion through this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub UpdateItems(child as MenuItem, targetURL as String)
  If child.Target = targetURL then child.Selected = true
  if child.Target = "" then child.Selected = false
  For each ch as MenuItem in child.ChildItems
    UpdateItems(ch, targetURL)
  next
End Sub
```

Called like this:

```
Protected Sub NavMenu_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
  Handles NavMenu.PreRender
  Dim a As String = Replace(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, "/Home.aspx", "/")
  For Each i as MenuItem in NavMenu.Items
    UpdateItems(i, a)
  next
End Sub
```

The code above should perform your checks on every MenuItem descending from NavMenu.

Note that I haven't actually tested this code and it might be possible to streamline it further, but I wasn't sure what kind of control NavMenu happens to be.

Comment: Thanks, this works the way it has to be without changing a single charector